# Text align in officer package

Tags: r, officer

I couldn't find any argument to adjust the text alignment in ph_add_text to justify.
Im using officer to make slide from r.
Or any suggestions to make slide from r that have text alignment argument.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you use `fpar` and set the text style in the `fp_p` or `fp_t` argument?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: But currently im using ph_add_text. But after I add new text, the new text not justify at center. How to put fpar in ph_add_text?

Answer (score 1):

This is a year and half later, but here's what I did. First, I make the text I want into it's own object with any properties that I might have. For simplicity, I won't add any properties, like font color, etc.

```
my_text <- ftext("I wish this were centered!")
```

Next, I make another object that contains the formatting of the paragraph that the text will be in (or text box in PowerPoint) using officer's fp_par() function:

```
my_format <- fp_par(text.align = "center")
```

Now, I can put it together--here's how it could go in a slide:

```
slide <- ph_with(slide_object, value = fpar(my_text, fp_p = my_format), location = ph_location(left = 4.90, top = 2.3))
```

The trick is, within the fpar argument, to have your text first and then, within the fp_p argument, to specify for fp_par() formatting as its own object.

Here's also more information on the function in case you're interested:

https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/fp_par.html

Comment: Which options are available to define or the entire document?